# Extract desired solutions from Reduce

Tags: equation-solving

I have the function

```
a = 1 - 3 Sin[theta]^2 Cos[phi]^2;
```

which I solve for 'phi' when $a=0$

```
sol = Reduce[a == 0, phi]
```

which gives me the result

[image]

How do I turn this output into a nice list of results for desired values of C[1], much like Solve[ ] would give me, so that I can use Plot[ ] and visualise the functions?

Comment: I fear I may get a 'duplicate' wrist slap as a similar question was answered by m_goldberg on one of my previous posts, and to certain degrees on other posts, but I don't understand well enough to translate to this particular problem :) Hopefully this simple example will help. As always thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Do you mean that you are looking for an entirely automated solution that would work for any Reduce output with no manual intervention?  That sounds difficult.  Otherwise is `{ToRules[sol /. C[1] -> 0]}` acceptable here?  The manual step was choosing a particular (integer) value for `C[1]`.

Comment: That's great @Szabolcs. Neat simple solution I was hoping for. What If I wanted a list of all the solutions for values of C[1] say from 1 to 50?

Comment: Not sure what's simplest in that case ... use a `Table`?  Can't really think of anything simpler than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ToRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToRules.html) is useful here.

If we manually set a value to the parameter `C[1]`, we can convert the remaining expression to a list of rules similar to what `Solve` would return:

```
In[5]:= rules = {ToRules[sol /. C[1] -> 0]}

Out[5]= {{phi -> -ArcCos[-(Csc[theta]/Sqrt[3])]}, {phi -> ArcCos[-(Csc[theta]/Sqrt[3])]}, 
         {phi -> -ArcCos[Csc[theta]/Sqrt[3]]}, {phi -> ArcCos[Csc[theta]/Sqrt[3]]}}
```

Notice that `ToRules` removed the `Sin[theta] != 0` condition, but it would remove the `C[1] ∈ Integers` condition if we don't make it go away manually.  I do not know (and did not check) when precisely it will remove any conditions.  So in more general applications this is something to pay attention to.

```
Plot[phi /. rules, {theta, -5, 5}]
```

---

An alternative approach here is to use `Solve`, which returns the same solution (in recent versions!) as `Reduce`, but in a different form:

```
Solve[a == 0, phi]
(* {{phi -> 
   ConditionalExpression[-ArcCos[-(Csc[theta]/Sqrt[3])] + 
     2 π C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers]}, {phi -> 
   ConditionalExpression[ArcCos[-(Csc[theta]/Sqrt[3])] + 2 π C[1],
     C[1] ∈ Integers]}, {phi -> 
   ConditionalExpression[-ArcCos[Csc[theta]/Sqrt[3]] + 2 π C[1], 
    C[1] ∈ Integers]}, {phi -> 
   ConditionalExpression[ArcCos[Csc[theta]/Sqrt[3]] + 2 π C[1], 
    C[1] ∈ Integers]}} *)
```

If `Solve` does not generate full conditions by default, as `Reduce` would, we can use the option `Solve[..., Method -> Reduce]` to force it to do so.

To make all these `ConditionalExpression`s go away, we can use `Normal`:

```
sol2 = Normal@Solve[a == 0, phi]
(* {{phi -> -ArcCos[-(Csc[theta]/Sqrt[3])] + 
    2 π C[1]}, {phi -> 
   ArcCos[-(Csc[theta]/Sqrt[3])] + 
    2 π C[1]}, {phi -> -ArcCos[Csc[theta]/Sqrt[3]] + 
    2 π C[1]}, {phi -> ArcCos[Csc[theta]/Sqrt[3]] + 2 π C[1]}} *)
```

Notice that this retained `C[1]`, but dropped the condition.  Now we can do

```
Block[{C}, Join @@ Table[phi /. sol2, {C[1], -5, 5}]]
```

to have a table of solutions corresponding to $C_1 \in \{-5, -4, \ldots, 4, 5\}$.  `Block` was needed to temporarily lift the protection from `C`.

Using `Solve` doesn't give anything new here, it's just a different way of achieving the same results. It may be more or less convenient than `Reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

Respecting generated conditions is important. In this particular equation (which could be solved by hand and the conditions are clear from the equation. You can access the solutions in a number of ways (e.g. using rules from `Solve`). Here is just one way:

```
a = 1 - 3 Sin[theta]^2 Cos[phi]^2;
sol = Reduce[a == 0, phi]
solc = sol /. Equal[x_, y_] :> Rule[x, y];
funs = Cases[solc, Rule[phi, x_] :> x, Infinity] /. C[1] -> 0
Plot[funs, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Orange}]
```

[image]